# Parsing date using BS4

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have the below section of HTML data, would like to extract the date information (e.g. 31-Dec-18). Appreciate if anyone could share a guiding hand using BS4.

```
<th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-19</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-18</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-17</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-16</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-15</time></th>
```

I use the bs4 parser option 'time', the text data (e.g. 31-Dec-15) was missing for all the entry, anyone know why ?

```
import requests
page = equests.get("https://www.reuters.com/companies/MBBM.KL/financials")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('time')

[<time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__gray___1V4fk TextLabel__regular___2X0ym"></time>, <time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>, <time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>, <time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>, <time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>, <time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg"></time>]
>>>
```

Comment: You can use `re.findall`. Eg `re.findall(r'(\d{2})-(\w+)-(\d{2})', date_string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
URL = 'th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-19</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-18</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-17</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-16</time></th><th scope="column"><time class="TextLabel__text-label___3oCVw TextLabel__black___2FN-Z TextLabel__medium___t9PWg">31-Dec-15</time></th>'


soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, "html.parser")

times = [time.get_text() for time in soup.select('time')]
for time in times:
    print(time)
```

prints:

```
31-Dec-19
31-Dec-18
31-Dec-17
31-Dec-16
31-Dec-15
```

Edit to get time with python from site use selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.reuters.com/companies/MBBM.KL/financials')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
times = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('time')

for time in times[1:]:
    print(time.text)
driver.close()
```

Output:

```
31-Dec-19
31-Dec-18
31-Dec-17
31-Dec-16
31-Dec-15
```

Note you need [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and in this case i import it from `c:/program/geckodriver.exe`

Comment: Hi UWTD Tv, thank you for sharing the code to process the wanted text output. However, the big question is why after using BS4 to parse the html file, the text of date content went missing. I am more curious to find out this missing piece of info.

Comment: @HorFamSoon No i have edit my answer. requests don't get times because times are loaded with javascript. But i have made a selenium version. So it is not bs4 that was your problem.